# Does Spring have similar open source package like PHP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, package

I am new to Spring and learning spring boot and I have used maven for dependency manager and have built a crud application and now I am looking to explore it more. I am wondering if spring has open source package website which list them like how we have https://packagist.org for php packages.

Comment: Like said @Mali, we have mvnrepository that would be the most similar to packagist for Java

Answer (score 0):

I am using [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/). It has dependencies for maven, gradle, ivy and some others.